# Configure Nginx with Amazon S3 and get html from S3 by using location of requested url

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

Is there a good way in Nginx to configure Nginx to get html content from S3 bucket?

I want to fetch static html contents from the s3 bucket. I tried proxy_pass to achieve this.

The url structure of the request is /file/path1/path2/. 
And the default conf file is:

```
location /file/path1/path2/ {
    proxy_pass http://s3.amazonaws.com/example-bucket/file/path1/path2/index.html;
}
```

Also, How to get the path1 and path2 from the requested url.
I've looked at the documentation and haven't found a straightforward way.

I'd appreciate a detailed explanation.

Comment: just duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926030/retrieve-static-file-from-amazom-s3-bucket/31926695#31926695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did for someone(probably newbie) who may encounter this problem.

```
location ~* ^/some_bucket/(.*)/(.*)/.* {
    proxy_pass http://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket/$1/$2/$1_$2.html;
}
```

~* means case insensitive regex match ^ means anything before () for catching parameters.

For example, User enters www.example.com/some_bucket/folder1/folder2/text

Then, it is processed as,

~* ensures case insensitive search(for case sensitive skip *(means just put ~))

^ matches www.example.com.

/some_bucket/ is matched then,

.* means any number of any character(for any numeric, replace with [0-9]*)

() ensures that matched values gets catched

So, $1 catches folder1

$2 catches folder2

Then

.* without parenthesis matches any charater but does not catch the matched value

Now the catched values can be used to find the file in amazon bucket using

proxy_pass http://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket/$1/$2/$1_$2.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-        location-block-selection-algorithms can be helpful

Comment: You also need to add a resolver inside the location directive for nginx to resolve the s3 bucket name.